# ngx barcode customization , Barcodes are hard to read

Tags: angular

Just a quick question .
Is there a way to make thick black lines on barcode thin using ngx-barcode?
I got a feedback from the client that when reading barcodes, it is difficult to read them properly. That's why it's difficult to move from application to receipt also It seems to happen with certain barcodes.Perhaps, but it seems that barcodes that are thicker are harder to read.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, you can't make lines thicker. But not because the limitation of ngx-barcode. Line thickness and spacing of the lines is important. Reading the white gaps in between black bars is what is used to determine the code. If bars were unproportionally wider it would most likely result in a wrong or invalid code. To help your client you could increase barcode overall size keeping aspect ratio. Or just increasing overall width while keeping aspect ratio. While all other options of ngx-barcode are with params, perhaps this reason is why there is no option to modify the thickness.

Comment: Thank you for the response . I also made a research about this and I really cant see anything about customizing barcode .